# が frequentally being used in ways I cant understand

Tags: grammar, particle-が, relative-clauses

I just started reading 上級へのとびら, an intermediate book with a lot of reading sections. Throughout my reading there have been a couple cases where I can't understand the usage of が in my sentences.

> 日本人が大好きな桜の花がいつ頃咲くかは、場所によって違います。

This sentence seems like it would work better with の, but from what I have been told it has to do with the adjective 大好き. What confuses me is that I have always thought that verbs finish a clause, but in this case 日本人が大好きな桜の花 seems to be the subject for this sentence. Why is this?

> 温泉には観光やレジャーが目的で行く人が多く、温泉では大きいお風呂に入ったり、おいしい料理を食べたり、浴衣を着たりしてリラックスします。

The part I don't understand here is 観光やレジャーが目的. 観光やレジャー isn't the subject I don't think, so I honestly don't know why its being used with が.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: After doing more research into this question, it turns out が was not the problem but my lack of understanding in the particles で and な.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

日本人が大好きな桜の花 is the subject of the verb 咲く, and the subject of the verb 違います is 日本人が大好きな桜の花がいつ頃咲くか. The whole structure of this sentence is like this.[image: structure of the first sentence]

In 観光やレジャーが目的, 観光やレジャー is the subject of 目的で（目的だ） and not 行く.  It says 観光やレジャー is the purpose of 行く.
[image: structure of the second purpose]

Comment: Could I ask how you made those lovely diagrams?

Comment: I used Adobe Illustrator. If you don't have it, tools for generating graphs like [Graphviz](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/) might help you.